# Need to Set Required Opportunity Variables before Record Save

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a form users are completing to create a record on Opportunity object when saved.

I need to automatically set values for:

- Opportunity.Name - value = OppName
- Opportunity.StageName - value = Assessment
- Opportunity.CloseDate - value = today's date

These values have to be set before the record attempts to save, otherwise I am met with an error.

Is it best to set these values within the VF page or within an extension?

I've tried this code within the VF page to no avail:

```
        <apex:inputText styleClass="fieldset" label="Client Name (First and Last Intial):" value="{!Opportunity.Customer_Name__c}"/>
          <apex:inputHidden value="{!Opportunity.Name}" id="Opp1"/>
          <apex:inputHidden value="{!Opportunity.StageName}" id="Assessment"/>
          <apex:outputText value="{0,date,short}" rendered="false">
<apex:param value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

My current controller is:

```
public class IntakeExtension {
    public ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;
    public IntakeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
             this.ctrl = controller;
             
        }

   public PageReference save() {
    // Returns PageReference only on success
    if(this.ctrl.save() != null) {
        return Page.Congratulations;
    }
    // There was an error.
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: you basically need to bind values to the standard controller's target object; this can be done in the controller, Javascript or via [URL params](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-for-lightning-tutorial/)

Comment: @cropredy - Do you have guidance on the actual code here? That's where I seem to be lost.

Comment: use [edit] and post your current controller

Comment: This has been completed - Thank you

Comment: @derekf answer is an excellent answer given that you already have a controller extension

Comment: Perfect - Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce doesn't really have a good way to set default values for fields. URL-hacking was one (ugly) option a handful of years ago, and it wasn't compatible when the Lightning UI was first released. That appears to have changed in Winter '20.

If you're not opposed to creating a controller extension, that's the approach I'd personally use. It should end up being pretty short and simple, like

```java
public class MyExtension{

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        // Fetch the (empty) record that the standard controller will have
        Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)sc.getRecord();

        // You can set default values here as long as it doesn't require any user input
        opp.StageName = 'Assessment';
        opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
    }
```

If you need to set a field based on user input (from another field), then you could take care of that by overriding the save() method

```java
public PageReference save(){
    // Assuming you saved the standard controller reference in an instance variable
    Opportunity opp = (Opportunity)sc.getRecord();

    // Fields set in your form are available
    opp.Name = opp.Customer_Name__c + 'opp (webform)';

    // And you can still set other fields here (instead of doing it in the constructor)
    opp.StageName = 'Assessment';

    // Finally, you can still call the standard controller's save() method (though I'm
    //   not exactly sure why you wouldn't just perform the dml yourself)
    return sc.save();
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you!